# Corollaries of Green-Tao Theorem?

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

there is already a good thread which discusses some corollaries of the Green-Tao Theorem, here:

[Constructing arithmetic progressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155822/constructing-arithmetic-progressions/157064#157064)

The question I was wondering about is of a similar flavor but isn't mentioned, namely, does there exist a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that given any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, can you always find a progression of primes $p$, $p+d$, $p+2d$, $\dots p+(k-1)d$ satisfying $d < cp$?

A (much) weaker algebraic variant, which is really what I'm ultimately thinking about, is the following.  It is much more likely to be known and/or easy, because I think there is a fairly well-developed theory for growth in numerical semigroups.

Let $S\langle n_1, \dots, n_k\rangle$ denote the (numerical) sub-semigroup of $\mathbb{N}$ generated by $n_1, \dots, n_k$.

Is it true that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist primes $p_1 < p_2 < \cdots < p_k$ such that $p_i \notin S\langle p_1, \dots, p_{i-1}\rangle$ for all $2 \leq i \leq k$?

Comment: I don't understand the weaker algebraic variant. Can't you just take any sequence of primes satisfying $p_1 > p_2 > \dots > p_k$?

Comment: Unfortunately not: $2 < 3 < 5$, but $2 + 3 = 5 \in S\langle2,3\rangle$.  The semigroup $S$ is comprised of all linear combinations of its generators (in this case, $2$ and $3$) which have integer coefficients.

Comment: I mean, for example, $p_1 = 5, p_2 = 3, p_3 = 2$. Did you mean to impose the additional condition that $p_1 \le p_2 \le \dots \le p_k$?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes you're right.  I meant to assume $p_1 < \cdots < p_k$.  I'll amend it in the original post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it true that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist primes $p_1 < p_2 < \cdots < p_k$ such that $p_i \notin S\langle p_1, \dots, p_{i-1}\rangle$ for all $2 \leq i \leq k$?

This is almost certainly true, although I don't think I can prove it rigorously. The idea is to take the $p_i$ to be large but close together. By the PNT the asymptotic density of primes about as large as $N$ is about $\frac{1}{\log N}$. Hence we should be able to find $k$ primes $p_1 < \dots < p_k$ of size around $N$ and within $O(k \log N)$ of each other, so taking $N$ to be suitably large compared to $k$ gives the result.

**Edit:** Okay, here's a proof, although maybe it's overkill. Thanks to the recent work on [prime gaps](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/polymath8b-bounded-intervals-with-many-primes-after-maynard/), we now know that there always exist numbers $H_m$ such that there are infinitely many intervals of length $H_m$ containing at least $m + 1$ primes. Pick a sufficiently large such interval.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  That works for sure; just pick a $p_1$ that is huge compared to $H_{k-1}$.